# How do I print the greatest of 3 numbers and letters lexicographically using compareTo

Tags: java

I need to find the largest of 3 numbers and letters lexicographically using compareTo and I already wrote the method and have the driver but I am not so sure how to call the method or if I have the method correctly written down any ideas?

```
public class Obj{
public static  Comparable  biggest (Integer word1, Integer word2, Integer
 word3) {
      Integer  big = word1.compareTo(word2);
        big = big.compareTo(word3);
        if(big<0){
            return word1;
            
                
        }else if(big>0){
                return word3;
            }
                else{
            return word2;
        }
        }

}

import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer numcompare;
        int lettercomp2;
        int lettercomp;
        System.out.println("Choose 3 numbers");
        Integer num1;
        num1 = scan.nextInt();
        Integer num2;
        num2 = scan.nextInt();
        Integer num3;
        num3 = scan.nextInt();

        numcompare = num1.compareTo(num2);
        numcompare = numcompare.compareTo(num3);
        System.out.println(numcompare);

            System.out.println("Choose 3 letters");
            String letter1;
            letter1 = scan.nextLine();
            String letter2;
            letter2 = scan.nextLine();
            String letter3;
            letter3 = scan.nextLine();

              lettercomp = letter1.compareTo(letter2);
                    
            System.out.println(lettercomp);
        }

}
```